# Hide Directory of other users on FTP 

Tags: ftp, vsftpd

I have used vsftpd to create ftp server of my ubuntu 12.04 desktop version. I have created too many users on ubuntu desktop.the problem is that..When I access it through FTP client with specific user,its shows all users directories. I want to show only directories that are intended to that user which I have loggedin, I want to hide all other directories.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a question on how to setup vsftpd than Ubuntu related.

If memory serves me well you need to add

```
chroot_local_user=YES
```

to your configuration (`/etc/vsftpd.conf`)

---

edit:

Found a source: https://security.appspot.com/vsftpd/FAQ.txt

Comment: Excellent @Nitin Mind if I remind you that AU works best by upvoting and accepting the best answer to your question? ;)

Comment: but now I have another problem, its shows hidden directory which is in the user's home directory. I want to hide that directories as well.. for that I have used..

force_dot_files=NO

but its not working.